# Could the recently announced Mac Minis power a theoretical 5K Retina display?

Tags: hardware, mac-mini

I'm curious, assuming that the Thunderbolt bus has sufficient bandwidth, would the Iris Pro graphics be capable of driving a 27" retina display?

Comment: It [sounds to me](http://www.marco.org/2014/10/16/retina-imac-vs-mac-pro) like the bigger problem is that current Thunderbolt implementations *don't* have sufficient bandwidth...

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it.
Best info I can find says it can do 3840x2160 resolution at 30Hz
Everymac hasn't been updated to include them yet, this was from zdnet - http://www.zdnet.com/new-improved-slower-mac-mini-7000034795/